# Adjust vis.js options to avoid crossed edges/overlapping

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

So I've read [this post](https://danklessons.wordpress.com/2017/06/22/4chan-thread-graph-visualization/), where someone visualizes 4chan posts in a graph. It looks very cool so I wanted to try it out myself. Everything is working good but I'm having some problems with my visjs options.

I am trying to get as close to the options he used. Sadly he hasn't posted them anywhere.

This is what I've got so far:

```
var options = {
  nodes: {
    shape: 'dot',
    scaling: {
      min: 10,
      max: 30,
      customScalingFunction: function (min,max,total,value) { return value },
      label: {
        min: 8,
        max: 30,
        drawThreshold: 12,
        maxVisible: 20
      }
    },
    font: {
      size: 12,
      face: 'Tahoma'
    }
  },
  edges: {
    width: 0.15,
    color: {inherit: 'from'},
    smooth: {
      type: 'continuous'
    }
  },
  physics: {
      barnesHut: {
          springLength: 1000,
          springConstant: 1,
          avoidOverlap: 1
      }
  },
  interaction: {
    tooltipDelay: 200,
    hideEdgesOnDrag: true
  }
};
```

My Problem is, that they still don't seem quite right and I also have trouble with overlapping nodes.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqgLytn1/)
Sorry for the unclean code.

Comment: A nice fiddle, the problem is perfectly reproducible; can be minified, though, all that parsing stuff is not related to the problem. I think if we solve this issue, we'll be able to mark various other questions as duplicates, but the issue is not that easy to solve..

Comment: Here's a simplified fiddle, should be identical with yours in terms of effect: https://jsfiddle.net/jqgLytn1/2/

Comment: Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/jqgLytn1/3/ Do you really need scaling for nodes? I think if you pair this with initializing coordinates of connected components, you'll be able to have no overlapping each time instead of sometimes